# Memory error in Eclipse (ADT) - Wrong Java version?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, adt

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04, 64 bit.
I recently updated my Java to Java 7:

```
isa@Daemon:~$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_60"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_60-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.60-b09, mixed mode)
```

And after this, my ADT bundle stopped working.

When I open up eclipse, I get the following error:
[image: first error]

when I click on 'ok', other errors show up like
[image: other errors]
[image: nice error]

And it starts working really hard (laptop gets hot), from time to time it stops responding and I'm forced to force quit it. 
It is a newly installed version of the adt bundle (from: http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

and I really don't know what to do. It worked before the update to java7 (yes, I have installed the 32-libs). Google told me that the first error I get is an out of memory error, but changing the heap size for eclipse can't be the solution as it worked before the update. I think there is something wrong with my java version.

By the way: I'm using an other version of Eclipse (Indigo) on the same laptop. This version works without any problems.

Attached: eclipse.ini:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20130327-1440.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20130807-1835
-product
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
-showsplash
com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.package.product
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.appendVmargs
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.7
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Declipse.buildId=v22.6.2-1085508
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M
```

and a part of the error log (I won't bother you by pasting all >10000 lines here)
http://pastebin.com/i7dUfg4h

EDIT: after changing the virtual machine that eclipse used, these errors disappeared but when I try to build a project (launch onto android device), I get following errors in the terminal:
[image: terminal errors]

and eclipse decides to terminate.

I appreciate any hints!
Isa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the unofficial PPA for the upgrade or manually install? Did you remove all traces of (I assume) OpenJdk1.6?

It's possible to have as many versions of Java installed as you like. You can configure which the OS uses by default with `update-alternatives --config java` and you can manually configure individual programs to use whichever you like by using the path to whichever version you like.

You should really be specifying the JVM that eclipse uses in the `eclipse.ini` and perhaps that's what this broken install has done. Maybe it points to the removed 1.6 JDK. It is important that you control your development environment instead of relying on the OS defaults which are subject to sometimes unforeseen or unknown, changes like this.

[Here is a link](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM) to the config file explanation but what you need to do is look through that to see where (if anywhere) Eclipse is looking to get and configure the JVM from using `-vm`  and `-vmargs`.

you should define the location of your desired JVM with:

```
--vm /path/to/java/bin/java
```

You can tweak the memory allocation among other options there too with `-XX:MaxPermSize`, `-Xms`, `-Xmx`.

Again, see the linked wiki for details.

You may also have a corrupt workspace or install. You can try making a new workspace or even a new Eclipse install.
You can also start Eclipse with `-clean` (perhaps `--clean`, can't remember) to reset it to default.

Since the error points to ADT you might get away with just [reinstalling that](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

Comment: I took a look at eclipse.ini and there was a line that said
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
I changed it to 1.7 but this didn't help. I'll now attach the error log and ini

Comment: That's not the configuration option I was suggesting. The one I was talking about was `-vm /path/to/java/bin`. Please see my answer and the linked wiki for how to add it and then come back with an update.

Comment: okay I've inserted the line
-vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
into eclipse.ini and it seems to work now with oracle (sun) java. I think the problem was that it was linked to another java version like openjdk. Thanks!

Comment: but - I still get out of memory exceptions while building the project - something still doesn't seem right here

Comment: Then try increasing the RAM allotted using the same wiki for guidance. Is it a particularly big project? What RAM have you available? You might try importing the project to a new, clean Eclipse install to see if it is the IDE or the project.

Comment: -I have 8gb ram
-I changed the maxPermSize to 1048m but this doesn't help either
-I've googled a lot by now and nearly all solutions include something about changing the vm. I've tried 'java-7-oracle' and 'java-7-openjdk-amd64' as vms. Neither worked.
-The project is rather big but it worked before so this should not be a problem?

Comment: Now that you have ADT sorted what do your logs say about the issue?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/xSfLMYyN 

I don't even have to build the project, clicking around in settings etc also causes eclipse to throw out of memory error and crashes

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54885/discussion-between-isa-and-indivisible).